# add comment on old existing code in github pull request

Tags: github, pull-request

one of my team mates created a pull request with some changes to a python module. while reviewing the changes i noticed that we can refactor the code and update existing code to make use of refactored code. so i want to put a line comment on the existing code which needs to make use of rectoring.

code which remains untouched is collapsed in a pull request. so i expanded that but github doesn't show a plus (+) on code that is untouched. so how do i put a line comment on existing code to highlight refactoring?

if this isn't possible via pull request then how should one accomplish this within github?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not directly possible, you could:

- open a second pull request with a modification to the existing code which needs to make use of refactoring.
- Mention in that new PR that it depends on the previous PR
- leave a comment on the line of the existing code (in the new PR where it is possible)

That way, you can organize the refactoring in the new PR instead of trying to do several things at once in the existing PR.